# jquery ajax success fuction response is empty after deployment.?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, wcf

I am using jquery ajax function in my project, in that static method i am connecting to wcf service. In local_host i am getting result from that static method. after deployed to iis expected result was not coming.

```
**ClientSide Code:**

$.ajax({
    url: 'SearchResults.aspx/GetSearhResult',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ SearchKey: searchKey, ActionName: action }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
//while debugging in browser this response is showing empty
            if (response.d != "") 
            {
              var obj = JSON.parse(response);
              **here i am binding result to html table**
            }
    },
    error: function (a,b,c) {
                        }
                    });


**ServerSide Code:**

[WebMethod]
public static string GetSearhResult(string SearchKey,string ActionName)
{
**Here i am connecting to wcf service In that service executing one stored procedure i am converting result into json string**
 retun Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
}

**Note:** i connected deployed wcf service in local_host using endpoints at that time i am getting result.
```

Comment: when u say it's not coming, u mean not result (something like 40X) or result came back with nothing (empty obj)?  i'm not sure if you connect to the prod when doing development.  some companies do not set up authentication in wcf setup for dev.  are you authenticated in prod?

Comment: It is not showing any error, the result came back as empty obj. FYI i am using same service in different areas at that time i am getting result.